# Turbolinks, limit javascript to one page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks, highlight.js

I am using highlight.js and applying this code to initialise the syntax highlighting for my code snippets on a blog app.

The following code is on my index.html page :

```
<script>
$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
  $('pre code').each(function(i, e) {hljs.highlightBlock(e)});
});
</script>
```

A code snippet should look like this originally:

```
<pre><code>A
B</code></pre>
```

And after applying the new style it turns into this:

```
<pre><code class=" hljs">A
B</code></pre>
```

The problem is that when I try to edit one of those posts on the edit.html page, in the editor I get the stylized version instead of the plain one, which I do not want. I want the new styles to be applied only to the index page. How can I  make that happen?

I should mention I have generated a scaffold with all the included views: index, new, edit etc.

Also I have the jquery-turbolinks gem installed.

The problem goes this way: I load index.html and I get highlighted code. I navigate to edit.html and get highlighted code. I refresh the edit.html page and lose the highlight (which is how it should be).

--------------------------------------------EDIT-------------------------------------

Tried this and it did not work:

in my aplication.html.erb:
`<body data-action="<%= action_name %>" data-controller="<%= controller_name %>">`

in my index.html.erb

```
<script>
    var data = $('body').data();
    if (data.controller === 'posts' && data.action != 'edit'){
        $(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
            $('pre code').each(function(i, e) {hljs.highlightBlock(e)});
        });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: A simple solution would be to use give your code a class on the index page and style according to that selector.

Comment: The problem is a bit more complex than that. Simply changing a class is not what I am looking for. I am having trouble integrating hightlight.js and froala.js in my app. I managed to strip down the problem to the one posted. Basically if I can initialise the froala editor with the original code <pre><code>, everything should work just fine. But because I can't understand turbolinks well enough I am having trouble keeping that javascript on the index page only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body data-action="<%= action_name %>" data-controller="<%= controller_name %>">
```

You can then read this in your script:

```
$(document).on('page:change', function(){
    var data = $('body').data();
    if (data.controller === 'foo' && data.action === 'bar'){

    };
});
```

Comment: Firstly got this error: `undefined local variable or method `action' for ..` Then replaced `action` with `:action` but it makes no difference.

Comment: Sorry its `action_name`, I was typing from memory which is foolish thing to do when you are nearly senile :)

Comment: @jcuenod `controller_name ` and `action_name` are from `ActionController::Base`.

Comment: You need to listen for `$(document).on('page:change')` . Edited answer. See https://github.com/rails/turbolinks

Comment: And DON'T put it in you views. Be a grown up and put it in your `application.js` or in some other external file.

Comment: I will do my best to grow up. Thank you :)

Comment: Why not use `location.href`?

Comment: @jcuenod also an alternative, but it puts a strong coupling between your routes and the behavior. Not that that is such a huge issue usually though.